# Limit of recurrent sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Study if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent where
$a_0 = b_0 = \frac{1}{2}$ with
$a_n=(a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}})^2$ and $b_n = e^{b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}-1$.

For $a_n$ I proved by induction that $a_n\leq\frac{1}{2} $ for all $ n\geq 2$, and although I haven't checked rigorously I'm pretty sure it is decreasing, so $a_n$ should be convergent, with limit $0$.

For $b_n$ I proved that it is increasing and I think it is unbounded but I don't know how to prove this.

Is there a set of conditions on a function $f$ such that for $a_0=\frac{1}{2}$, $a_n=f(a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$ is convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can show inductively that $b_n>0$ using $x>0\Rightarrow e^x>1$. If $b_n$ converges to $b$, then $b\ge 0$. Let $n\rightarrow\infty$ on both sides of the recursion, $b = e^b -1$. Note that the function $f(x) = e^x-1-x$ has a unique $0$ at $x=0$, because its derivative $f'(x) = e^x -1>0$ for $x>0$, so it's strictly increasing over $[0, \infty)$. Therefore $b=0$ is the only possible limit of $b_n$.

Now we have a problem: Because $f(x)>f(0)=0$ for $x>0$, $e^x-1>x$ for positive $x$, therefore $b_n = e^{b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}} - 1 > e^{b_{n-1}}-1>b_{n-1}$, so $b_n$ is increasing, in particular $b_n\ge b_0=\frac{1}{2}$, so it cannot have $0$ as limit. Therefore $b_n\rightarrow\infty$.

Note that the $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ doesn't play any significant role in the argument. It's hard to know when it will make a difference.